# VPN connection timeout

Tags: java, tomcat, vpn

I have a web-app running on my local Tomcat. I have my VPN setup on my machine. I observe the followings:

1. web-app (running on the local Tomcat) gets connection timeout when accessing the database through VPN
2. the database URL is specified with the server IP
3. tracert  shows the VPN is reached
4. ping  gives me "timeout"

Something more weird is this: if running this web-app (on a local Tomcat) on a virtual machine, the database connection has no issue!

Why connecting from a virtual machine works but connecting from my native machine does not?

Comment: Which OS do you use? What is the exact network setup?

Comment: @Henry What network setup I should look at?  I am using Windows 10. Having "Network status" page correctly shows that I am connecting to internet through a VPN.